# Equilateral Triangle Problem With Trig

Tags: trigonometry

I have an Equilateral triangle with unknown side $a$. The next thing I do is to make a random point inside the triangle P. The distance $|AP|=3 cm, |BP|=4 cm, |CP|=5 cm.$ What is the area of the triangle?

I have seen this problem posted here before and solved, but done without trigonometry. How would you do this problem with trigonometry?

Comment: For reference, the earlier question which addresses this problem by a collection of algebraic and geometric methods is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/913675/137524. (This doesn't give a purely trigonometric approach, of course, but may be a source of inspiration thereof.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Here my point is $D$ instead of $P$, $s$ is side of triangle:
$|AD|=3,|BD|=4,|CD|=5$
Using cosine rule:
$$\cos \angle ADB=\frac{9+16-s^2}{24}\\
\cos \angle BDC=\frac{16+25-s^2}{40}\\
\cos \angle CDA=\frac{25+9-s^2}{30}\\
$$
Also $\angle ADB+\angle BDC+\angle CDA=2\pi$

So, $cos \angle CDA=\cos (2\pi-(\angle ADB+\angle BDC))=\cos(\angle ADB+\angle BDC)$

$$\begin{align}
cos \angle CDA&=\cos(\angle ADB+\angle BDC)\\
cos \angle CDA&=\cos(\angle ADB)\cos(\angle BDC)-\sin(\angle ADB)\sin(\angle BDC)\\
\end{align}$$
Now we need to solve:
$$\frac{25+9-s^2}{30}=\frac{9+16-s^2}{24}\frac{16+25-s^2}{40}-\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{9+16-s^2}{24}\right)^2}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{16+25-s^2}{40}\right)^2}
$$
Or:
$$\left(\frac{25+9-s^2}{30}-\frac{9+16-s^2}{24}\frac{16+25-s^2}{40}\right)^2=\left(1-\left(\frac{9+16-s^2}{24}\right)^2\right)\left(1-\left(\frac{16+25-s^2}{40}\right)^2\right)$$
Or:
$$\frac{s^8}{921600}-17\frac{s^6}{230400}+103\frac{s^4}{92160}+119\frac{s^2}{25600}+441\frac1{102400}=\frac{s^8}{921600}-11\frac{s^6}{76800}+47\frac{s^4}{10240}-2017\frac{s^2}{230400}+441\frac1{102400}$$
Or:
$$\frac{s^6}{14400}-\frac{s^4}{288}+\frac{193s^2}{14400}=0$$
As $s\neq0\Longleftrightarrow s^2\neq0$:
$$s^4-50s^2+193=0$$
So:
$$(s^-25)^2=432$$
Which gives:
$$s=\pm_1\sqrt{25\pm_212\sqrt3}$$
Since $s>0$:
$s=\sqrt{25\pm12\sqrt3}\approx 2.0531,6.7664$$

Comment: I did not think the problem would be this lengthy! Since I was supposed to solve this problem in 5 minutes, is there a faster approach? Second of all, when you say "or" are you making another equation by manipulating the previous one or making a completely new statement?

Comment: @Lionblaze16 manipulating the previous one!